# Have a static url to host a picture that i will update monthly (iPhone app)

Tags: iphone, ios, image, photos

Okay so I want to load a image from a URL in my app, however this image will need to be updated every month manually, therefore its not practical to have to submit a new update to apple every time the url changes. So does anyone no of a picture/file sharing site that would allow me keep the same URL for the image even when uploading a updated version of the image?

Comment: you can use free services like http://www.noip.com/. You create a free domain and you manage it yourself to point to the image you want.

Comment: i'm going out on a wing here, but you could look into something like downloading a txt file from drop box and reading that, it's a bit corny of an idea but it wouldn't involve creating your own domain and i think could be less work if it's possible, but no guarantees, i do know that you could download images from like Facebook, so you could up load an image with the url as the name of the file and then download that image, all of this is so hacky but it keeps things simple.

Comment: @Caolán Hamilton, Have you find any solution yet?

Comment: anyone solve this? @pkc456

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the same url for the image that you want presented hosted on your domain or a hosting site.

So something like

http://www.mydomain.com/appImage.jpg

That you always call to and always is the address of the relevant image.  Basically the URL is just a location that you can store any image at.

Answer (score 0):

Up to my knowledge, in order to achieve this you will need a static URL. So that means you'll have to buy a domain from a hosting service.
Or if not you can use Google Drive for this. But you'll have to do some more coding for this.

> Try using Google Drive:
>
> 1. Upload a text file(*.txt) to your Google Drive and get a shareable link. Convert it to a direct download link.
> 2. Next save whatever your image as a String (base64); I have attached some interesting coding examples below.
> 3. Then give the file link to your app; download the file; read the String(base64) convert it back to image format.
> 4. When you want to update the Image convert it to a String; open the Google Drive; edit your file using ***Drive Notepad*** (Do not use
>      Google Docs) and simply save it <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

Useful Links:

- [Google Drive Direct Link Generator](https://sites.google.com/site/gdocs2direct/)
- [Convert between UIImage and Base64 string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251340/convert-between-uiimage-and-base64-string)
- [Converting between Image and Base64 string in iOS](https://gist.github.com/JeOam/b5aa75d8c5b267f1e688)
- [Java BufferedImage to PNG format Base64 String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7178937/java-bufferedimage-to-png-format-base64-string)
- [Convert image to base64 with java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28268511/convert-image-to-base64-with-java)

Hope this helps.