# Convert Base64 to image file in png format without saving the file. Possible

Tags: java

I am using Apache httpclient to call a REST web service. This service returns image in base64 format. I want to convert this to image in png format but I don't want to save this image file. Reason being there are more than 10000 users and if I keep saving all the images, it would consume a lot of memory.

I am using JDK 1.7

Is it possible to achieve this ?

Comment: This might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7178937/java-bufferedimage-to-png-format-base64-string

Comment: What format is the image in to start off with, in the base64 string from the client??

Comment: You can put everything together in memory (without ever writing to disk) using streams but it will use memory of a constant factor greater than one times the space needed for the image itself.

Answer (score 0):

Create a BufferedImage instance from whatever format, assuming that is supported by ImageIO... I'm guessing this is from disk - you've not said in your question

```
    BufferedImage original = ImageIO.read(new FileInputStream("test.png"));
```

Write as PNG into a ByteArrayOutputStream

```
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(original, "png", outputStream);
```

Convert resultant byte array back to base64.

```
String output = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(outputStream.toByteArray());
System.out.println(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be hard - you can use memory-based streams instead of file-based ones:

1. Decode the base64 image using, e.g. [Apache Common's codec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html), into a byte array.
2. Create an input stream from the byte array, using [ByteArrayInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html).
3. Read the image from the stream via [ImageIO.read](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read(java.io.InputStream))
4. Save to to PNG and output as a stream to the client.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Could you please provide a code snippet for this. I am fairly new to this and don't really have any idea. Let me know if you need any further information.