# Encoding a file to Base64 in Java

Tags: java, encoding, base64, encode

The Imgur API allows you to send a Base64 of an image to upload that image.

I have tested that this works when I send a Base64 that looks like this:

```
/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/2wBDAAQDAwQDAwQEAwQFBAQFBgoHBgYGBg0JCggKDw0QEA8NDw4RExgUERIXEg4PFRwVFxkZGxsbEBQdHx0aHxgaGxr/2wBDAQQFBQYFBgwHBwwaEQ8RGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaGhr/wgARCADIAKQDASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAHAAAAQUBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgABAwQFBgcI/8QAGgEAAwEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgMEAQUABv/aAAwDAQACEAMQAAAB3xJsmd2cDMwdZG4lK6OC1HHQKytQCJEtwESpVG0o0pZiatCTosZEs8JMwmaTpN3EpHvn5/K2zdJy1HM73Gt38ysDPby5nU+f7GixpgxCYNA063zJ1uMzpZO7FK9qV/njHz+4HKfU/P6RySkVbN38WWrrPUPFfZ+bSTCKSKMotGZCtGRJY5kSHWd0hr8X03nnX5WW0dLt886bzRXa/OjBPT23q3kXrnPcIOwKYXbRlSW4STrqRCQlHxuz5xbLf2uLqdLn3saWibtCsqiHzRSW9zZ9k+fvf4CZk6NQkzAJOjE3EpL0TIC5nzDp8rpxScnfvUr5jpOf2+b0j5/0DilHT1MvoOhFv+mmISMgYSkYC3JUK9khC8PSeCVtHwja9Z4WpPHtpY3Y5udYq2Of0uqwppiVh2NLI97rN3ziQfe4FAbIHmiMGzKNAcwuEV7uDbkgZGc+fice/X6k+S4DPb00sk7YMXE2MQK7EwWLQ9D3fNu3Lj7FnIeZmms1Du6IhyOy+Jq1Go5XmpanWQGfNW8+vKHUx1WK82K2CpUKYrGmE7U6HU8l0LuTu2MMRk21hrC7sYF833ZeT2+YuloUekxevJnUrtYr87o+eXMt7TmN/ApgrEJnXLNHJQi1dzkUutJnWsluqJYHWDZo/O9qEZshwrmpArySrHI1ma99sO9lyti6ZWg1kclmfBoLaqblPSjLV6ayFqaUTSIsrjNbzc+DoNNXuPt+l3Jm+Ryekc60OSkqgL9EI2NcoyX2rxA1avjid2LLCSYMQJATMkkpbiSR1NJLF3bKU73hSW3PrpMXkUkujPXFI2iSXvTpIs//xAAqEAACAgEEAgICAgEFAAAAAAABAgMEAAUREhMQICEiMDEUMgYVIyRAQf/aAAgBAQABBQI/gOFgv/UOFQweRqOKyyLm3uPxT3IK2SaqhR3mgyaUyitrNrTGH29h+HVdSGnw1tMaYWrK1ceZ2jSytpZERydbqwLTsS2l9B+C3aSlBNK6yLqfPJv91hUmnjSBHWzI3Zo1RdQbbbyfAP4LNfvu6v8A8nIf615atbBfV3mkZmuXxbbR9VSlMjLIh8HwPwW7R7ZJDztNvhiV8hM8Uh1qeKCOHnlPTa1iyiLEh9B72pOC3mbuUczqBys7Y0rKHmbn2HNFkMOE+o9ZXEUer6hLUiGtuLEnVqAsjqaQgYrAhz9Jf7gEmkVjqn1HrrL8KFlXntzVVQizJXyzaM2OeYAkhDH6/vO9Y0gbY/seg9das9C2u8WJ7EVlSuA5FIKMc2pyyq42YZXhDNFoc0zj03wet7Vkm1SYu4WBe+emOHHc0qy3JX0iGOOwpOKvLKEUsGoHxvm/kZ/74nhWzDqGnTaXOkjT1KoMzTyFDZkWQ6ezJNPfO8tn+SbNdqsnYrw1dclow6drpv2fIwessSWI5f8AH5IMnPSYlByReOUjtZnrdss8TxVdSjEMAtfHNJEou1a7yzfzy8b+d8bbjfIFwHi8u/KBuuZgI7E47U1BjIi4V3yAmKSjb5DnnPA/x3ed8LBR/qUJNyUyh0M0srOCx3K/2dmsXZ3/AJmXCP4wwHFxHxJd85Z2YD53y+TKJmrUjPdknZQ0UUkhYZHG8pnbg47ZVsScmxfEB5urbYr5yztXN83w40XM3XFizJ9cctJnDxDO1YytwiktPJHtgHmEcWD74JNsMhODN838ahZ7wExo/s2N4jjSfNQ2lsSrw8gYBiHjgbfA2b4pzfN8ml+oQ5InGN3GEjG/RwFkxjku/lfA+cL8cjl5YDi/rnhfGO+KjHJuxskjZGSu0iupUEfIXJJfrM/OXxvm/gnF/atviRuQ0UKY1+jC51KBRJ/kJAk1buburtkViujm/wDLOpWMDeJxJYMBOCsxzpcmOGNMjfjhiebDNHGWuOuHUSSl6cDunczrxk4kZt9AN1PDFh7MbTbSKr74ejD1jOaAGzI+bnN9g05fC7b7nOTkYv658caXngkwToypw2jr0SKywonRJjcVOoR1rKvDJHiI7ladhgtaVhHSndlpPDNNAVxY/k/Bxf0fRGAxTkVnhi2WlwCAZzhK7xLgk45JAJmem6l0ljLuxzkc+fK5/8QAJhEAAgIBAwQBBQEAAAAAAAAAAAECEQMSITEEEBMiQRQgIzJRBf/aAAgBAwEBPwEQl2jwRlq2+RtDJMfdCQjqOq8G0RPq+r/J8Iw5Pp/U80XtY/sXaeTxx1Eox6iLyXuR+p/TEmxdN1OKX5ImCOhPahyHI1vuj/Qm6UUYVc1EhPJhnUWSyZckd2eVz/Yl9ubLoMmrMvUw4nGrPE1M3SpIrTLs2X3zTWN3W4+pcpe8rMWVY/atyeVzfsZVq2TE9jUN99VGWKyqnyJPU5SFJLHsZJR1xmRl5oKQoLQ75FIRqRqssnljHgUlwhcDfqr5MSrHRJuqY7iLLR5WWZLmtIqTIJcvkerS5RRKLyVXBdIZ1K9tiy+2bJKNKJFyTIErlGk6MFx9RjslDUShT3KNMmeD+s8DxnhnyWxRjB9mkabJ4tR9Oz2s1NfBHKrPJI9L/hoUvkcYobhHkU1Ww3fdE1RqIwixbbIeKMuTQlIpLv8A/8QAKREAAgEDAwMEAQUAAAAAAAAAAAECAxESBBAhEyIxFDJBUQUgQmGBsf/aAAgBAgEBPwEY3YZLySg4rL4I3FyU0LZjJkmaXRLULOo7L/SNHR6VdP5f9lektTyenqRWTVkRQt2O5Tp9Waiym3SkoW4JuhfKfA9RQmu1mqm5zTvdCW1t5I/G0025MrWUMidOFaOTFSpwZVji+BbW2uUKSmrsgoU+SrWUoux1k6Zw+St3JGIkW308M1Zvg6EYxtFWK9NyWJSpqKeJTniuUT7mYiW9ilU6bLpxUUTp9/cU4NRlFGPTk0ifv4Ghli20KM2+RQ+yfkV8nbwfvFThJ3JwHSudJbUXjO4o9t2YtLgbSdmU2oXy8kaeTIRsi1zEx201OL7pEWpokWtK7HaTuIX6LRQpv4RS1P8AB6uHi52+RO5kkepUT1cfoWof0dd/RihokuB2+hVJs6rXwRnx4E5P2qw4v5ZGKWzJu22JObTG8uWRqyj4KcnKN3stv//EADkQAAEDAgMECAQFAwUAAAAAAAEAAhEDIRIiMRNBUWEEECAjMDJCcVJigZEUcqGxwQUkQDRDgoPR/9oACAEBAAY/AvBzGJ/xSHXBUvmp0bjqWf8AoQdTIc06Ef4ffVADw3qabMQPxJx6Njo03elFrnVGk6xchNpdN/uKJ0M3hSPHy3rv8g/lbbpjy2bx6ioAw8ghU05ShrS6QzeN6pisAy0S391TpjHVqBgs1q2j6QpUz5byT4rq1bQbuJQ6Z08HaVPIPhCyuWKpm91jkQ30jVQG4ag0KbbDhH68VtKsRT1HxeM19e9CiyWt+birDEWFWELH0kGo/wBIjRdw18i86Qm1W0mMqDWH+ZS7o7abvlKG0BbTd5iE19MhzXCQR4tUc1ZMcysKWIZmOEoFrg+LwE/8OddRhlOpfhaTKjrh3D2Cx1DiJXRqL8WEhz44t4ff9kGUmhrGiAB4jGDzVXhgVQnQuUnRNwnRBxO9Oc0kGUZvPFRJA5J1dzC8Me2HE6Tb+fDfUdo0SqFPo9QMqk5nR910d3SO+2eLdGqlpwOdeCsKGO4QwiAvdysoGqqhzjtdqy07vDdG9zf3VXaEmHw1dxinfKw1BdB+/emrvmOa3cS1fVcFhot93HVAbyZ8Og1tPave/K3mielEea7W2UU6DWTreU8fDp1DBeq5sudw5LDixDgVbRQgagy8OKa5tP8ADs4uP8eG3Y95ToMMc3Jxq0g1wqEGCg1/lQq0icKy/qs7sO4ysYcXmm7NukLa+lxhWIXRNocu0B80+HUo1JwvEGFD/L6HjQqv0lhwRGPfdF5uUNkfJqm7MRa/ui9mjWy7mE+k8ta0C7h601gaG0+agkOadCELOxjeoezbt9Mu0WxfRbTkWgz4Rp1mh7DuKqH+m14a4Xp1Lgo0DkdGbCJKwO8uvUy0zZB/RyHMd6SYw8kMoADrnnwXRodLt/JZqbZ+IZT+iIxFh+ZUX8HeG6dIVTBmMAD7KbHksxVN/wALgVWBGRzo9l0cB8tqX9k10HAHW59YcEKbzf09d1bsS4wBvKIo964cFedkWHEAdEXQiYa0clZCeKqB4AZtJWJginQZAMalUWjj13QjwNno3UpoawVDq7Erd2zSyzceuGAn2RDcoc6ahP7KGnZ0twWEOxNbp2GjruVr2CSYtvR2Y7oWHPmhyupPXT6LSAa5zodUHFHaDFDjZO9IOUAdmfA2TDFP1c+ok9ilUpk4gZeDxQAEYjKazl2Z7ZjtywkIVJmKN/eE3F5sPbjf2rAqGU3n6I7QYTzU0ofHA3WYR11Kd5pswpx7Y6rNcs9YALB5zxlGB0dhHGpiRwODv+uFNXG4/mhHHivoZXfMe9vyvhRTfUawaAmV/t3+6xGHNbrdVHVJzAmykTh4wsha/wCqizfcqa7sfysP8r/TscD8TUI6LTbz8v8AKhpph/yjEm7N9ZzeYhHK76uVnKNq4/VHeFpog6LTCxYRrC0IXd3PBYzQfH5VhNLEQodjpv8AZZak/wDFZXOPIrNgA/KF5h9ld6AMmNFfd1AF7oHPsZldNY6QAspOt4K7ym+fdYaDHUx+XVTmZ+iO0dM8Chs21GVx63b/AHWZpUU2uceQU7M/VTEDnZNlhAO9ZwOQlGW390MWWVrPavP2W9aFWY76PKG2bUI5PXleowx+YSsmL7QskgLFhzcVElvu1XB7f//EACcQAQACAgEDBAMBAAMAAAAAAAEAESExQRBRYXGBkbEgocHR4fDx/9oACAEBAAE/Iduow9YTmcdDJgKh4uU/i3MyuoMdvUh1OgigVI8k8ez7r/0hnXtFjK4dxR0qVE6PQ8/hfUjL4H8c/AmNv0HL2g6M2vB/3zCCHmP/AAeSYbtet7h/jEA0IJKiSo9TuV1Iw6EccTs+XiKvcFfPaNXCYN0cnPGR9ZWaXh6p3P6S3qLv3iEosHWxyuIq1GPqfp0qPQYj+bydvlwBB+XXtmsfUMW9ncjKi42Qroav3AinePJGG0EVd+UEaVh7RlMAAMAS6l3FF6PP5Ed4EP0tcvQIXHIgXlitCkeWZgDApPJ7yvd9EMuMFselUSuQ7eSWNByP1LUJEwk2lzToMda6V0CMzAKexqDbi3dygG8Qnx4irC6JVy4q/NDskZeolqxtIN1LtO8s9cBFXLvlcUzENQEwhF6aznrUqGZa9Kx3nb8DDFojiOqUOYJfIEfGYD0p6RxbZY+YxlUFgs1AaHaopIW8hD3F8Shi9HppOepNrHftB4KvDxeEqrZ0tUVdHY+4nL/6B3j8WlItRBqqvEOCinSChVaqWcEa45382TdjCPRY/Ai2WRBV32SjZb0jVTRCmTsWCXTYZQHjfnzNaywWPjIEvrA4unLNWl85PMz+2v7Lo9DoR6Cc9SPjpuJ7mFuwSyhnUw57J/R2mO1vK0oUdVmBIAthtw7SzbGxu4SHmrt4jWEJPZM+E2228r22goDsV+JTn8K9AF8YsnxUC+TcjmvY5jcassMUAoNuI2z4YSs18WHHFzT7Smh481H++DFVXeWgA+Ygha0EVf6mDF9p5TKXCUj1ZeXuUzfJuNh/3xAxqywYf937RaV9TJvla8W8S2AByhOM4avTZXvK0W5L457VKJ7hbfOIJyA5xKxY+LWVEGYGh85WwqtVZxOY4MS8wYgjvpcGbvalExKI/oL/ANmPWFtlZDx5m0DKy/cv+sq3LJdWuv3U2NLlFy77Q0xyZThAgQ8HkWRcE0qn5NH4mVw0aPuRl6PJkrmZacTLcMy6htqXMJcuEMM6st7Q5bdHcpuNstUHIRt5mWtr4ZmvjF3llKgWiGjvOn6gkCg3hX/EFsCA8xeZrybPJ2h2MKwYV7GLF6HhDWpQRuM2qwH3leQENLd757RW20luKO8El1WZ0xTsqX8zPIn7DUuOPCyTaveEN1t3o3FUCpWyGxdNlPaFslzwYrXRXMuMlLYfUlATdge8aJx0McdorW02LeZWPYCaipaFtLxNlnxFp/H3D6CJx3hG++N5gdBiZgDMslRNyoWBKuM5RjeVaApeh5Yi1Lb4/wBSli+Lu8EQz+DtGKzU5G8SV58Q+HGtoK/2Z+8Yq5g6ncldoCtRxGUeirH8mt1HY+sTMZcdEWafr6THqDuHiEuco7jVaHkEeUTR27w6HF31ehLYR69IAWRITh9+mpzBCeUjnJLMKvmHKUuK6QqOWXwyrhVXoQW0oKdu366GIsQaipiaW2Bkx0H3RY5l8sZmUUeC43XjqSqpciicg2A/TcVKjWTmP0F9ujy5KP7Kp1gPYhLgYQKalm40Yj+qWVR4JQLnxmN86eAisQWNw9gnjzKH2YlPxEFPapRecXk1HPbrc+puipUzh9xp/kxMxZxxCwzr94yulycCWo4KPwwudx2yLY2sbz5gvQax+JYyNUco4MQrP94g+EN1fbcshrKNv1KzSXM1FdFyFO7MLmXk4Bi+TPIhmkr3OZa+8piqnnxXM0V93aJk+ADZLii9m7B7bhfKTmxDJR2MQurvxfGJj1wu6zwE7EEFupiDT3Etzbc7cQFYhfdYcvWFmA3HNjXJAOTCCTs1uEgbSwOd8Q2GteL39Qc6OaZ8jL8ygTRwv/KKxuTklXq1ZjwH9imN5rHzPCwmYoGPig/DmMhUat7QW7VcQ/lDdR/sc3ra0ZgUHkwiBR3lx5esDbh32mez8Sns/EKC/YI1gL8TuJ4zBOO8VoR2zV+mPDxeT/Y1Q1dqoiwQlPN+5n5jtLaat8oIyctRngww2ka9I+T4jZ0yns/Ep7PxC04d9p//2gAMAwEAAgADAAAAEHFPQc6ZbIw/crMYmGT4O7zlCwthnch91AzB56vC3beuga3fk8XEe27QmZ37MgnELGj6b84Oqg8brPkMjMT47LLSc4PjMxgrioJcI8O1YoOb36zLZ7iejp+n+gMpFebIupMFsXHXvvfn/IIgP//EACcRAQACAQIEBgMBAAAAAAAAAAEAESExQRBRYbFxgZGhwfDR4fEg/9oACAEDAQE/EA4LIFkVYQ07Wp8+HWXKuBjaQSmBmoOEc1MCpX2luBd7Qr2Y+QR1TXa7HfvLYLKX5c47jx1QohPD4VGnPxLgOPp5ENr086xzrMEzdeutle2+NtZW1/gDDHLq7/EEczu0PcqLtJo8vSHilcuV7wFStKPQx+4rY6SyVKiOjFU9/mIAreTh8Se6EK9GrimsPseL9ZZBctMXgWgcKiOWryrY01yv5YFssFYwctI0vQ++cIO/T75QbDF9fKOAVvrrAxGWxmSAcA0vSv3KtUbHTJcqGmolRmis6bLXREHeWMZz3SDqYXLiPnwLCdUEXKI3FM2w0TpBrWGmNko89MeMoAVV9/rBPIRLG4iaLeEZQufL+9YBttQ5wqvS/jkW9IkK9TTXgc4gg2jHMYLpgyXls35Mq5qxJQwZOf38wpZwd8vavU4LmW+seocJjiTN7BBmMr0gWiVlJmM7wp3198xp3nPwawR9cOcRRiYmryg3dnrOQ2eGZYCqOi/uOZn98I5qE1NbG2ETgAgFzAeIoIbaQDoiaiFIGk2kTHD/xAAlEQEAAgIBAgYDAQAAAAAAAAABABEhMUFRgRBhcZGxwaHw8dH/2gAIAQIBAT8QfBUibh1SGBlaePM9Tk3AC0xHSXt+Bq/EQExXHaNJ1X+QcKKMNpeN2fRFLUjg4p6Vx8S6pjWevl++0oPBcuyaRpVh6Rz6RtjDGIVoI9/fMoZ2dBzXYmpEwdG8/wB7TFAb8SWTihu5rHvGpceaY7QAe4moviHhYbZrAz4FrwO+a8elRymPTU2AQ7MTkchn1iOtolFGrfqClO5WMrMQdBrzva71j+EKt92/eDrY5/ekCOO41yoc8d481AdCGMplEIWjW9dzkg5vn2jPUjNUK3jdef1HhrHwMsh0YrDLzGBWoL0I3YwC27hsDz5rPPbefSWZrcFHDBu+sueIJPiez+/8jhUKrW/xClbydfX3jWOIlUUMxvKyiow8OpcOkFmImgszACm/jB8ygwlXFqblTdqGK+n5gVTQPM+/qCsi7ncYqcQ5kcar9P3MtMKKyfnG3/cwQXA/EPiPtBfh3+oRQD6k16RGy2Zih7/NxLUtBLIomkS8yjEwMTIgRaAtkWNXw//EACYQAQACAgICAgIDAQEBAAAAAAEAESExQVFhcYGRobEQwfDR8SD/2gAIAQEAAT8QsLLt5gucv3LQMv3EeX7ltqi9/cLyt+43yfuXeW6lwgCH0C8XxfqZsrKR2/czu37lt8/czysC0uPMTsnzLXt+4CG37jdu/uMvPPcz/wAcxKgQMygwxHeGDNRyKBrE2JBgbABfTOWgHTm5iSgcexgBEBaFLfiOI7NkTFfwYolIZngwWOeYM0zuJjUB4hiG0IOC4svcyLfuC8jFe/d91A5EsH1RPEbcNw281ydUzVXcrqIUCUi5y+z/AJF5rs8128te87jXb65Es/f/AMAPLHG4CmmswUq7YYTQzLD1MHGplEvITZWVZ8i5HBy10zMJTLbs35fOfUTtByrTdrn5i9rxdU+X9QtR5bPE814H9FUaoQ25Fy3SeIFHhzhLpC67YFQM95FoDgdwFxUaWw3cqZnuWt9sGJuBnMCtRpKgRKIQE5X2l+i2JZE1VWsLWEp7eYzcDBQ335i4am4W7fmEB9oCKyEwHct5XMRppH+o+FEeT4W2scVUuVIdycBXBa34wblAMQBQGgD4lOVR4IxrMGjNQKfcS17/ALmmG2VTmG7JuCriioOwwjzQq+4MoRBgO8/E3HKGW34giKVMXRpdGiXoibAQdtr+IfxVEgc7zsGnxBYABEa4uk341D7DVYjtduBx1pgxWWRRYjBdrlhx3HftG1bhW9za+4mY5RIQFS5qBZu/4Cn1+ZepgdmAwSKcGFYXcdLhloqgMCWZOaxEwjWtBN2B1KQcYOUN0C0aa8Mt2zpWvNvdxBSALICHdKHgtWQXAKAWgIoUux/GS9zlXbCev4EAFjZ3E4AAoyL0yU/1OFGj6jOchX6lDAQbcH/ZZQtKUFQiMBWUdGt4gIwF8enHsnxVlo/3mG2lbVJGeU5LF9y9ODEtl8fwNx5e44Xtg5zC7uZEy+j9XYLr51K+5qN2CwlW5x4jtaeyq2wKEL7R+HApu+Q4047jw75WBpqKS05N3mNrU0NLmQuyx/LKrUgo+JqU4FqwJZoxOzWqLk1cXLYq5ia3bM9w4mpme47+X9xC/wCNCJmaLVibHOtQSJ60mgOAOYwRggPB81Gru8JPIxNxRsyVx/1HaIso3eeJgCa7t0WkJjwGr8MO6lAJdAFXFJOiD4ejxEIbAt6B/ZXwSyXbweI9ShEJOK5gU33Ly9sHuVz/AASY89ooVy0XivsiUwtq2VFl/OJS7VGrVJUKYvljZslVlS6d/D8REFJA/wB5qLOo4bIfgFXysoBNVRLhEf8AGyWcioLtn2rVwQtRdh2wQXbsK8ejCRDZNA+f8qMzJt0W7oiWruXwcS8ZlXiBTnmaY9sIZIYFaALVaAj4TjaWpXrAPQvM0DonVB22/wCGZe7dAKa4zxOfVe7gvkbqvPEOqG8g7OM79QuUMwZlLVVWLlOowGxDCsx8g5qCAC42SwwT9RnEuBJn6inR4Y5Gn8onNdP5lI0MNbtnxK6HueUF+CCj7hpPll4hplVRopB5Hs35quYUtf8A/EA5ffJmOGu7gwAWYDVu/CY72Nza7ZQ6TXssKDWCBYuEb5Mph0HZQsb0fjE3uADFa0KSHWvUuVYxAvQ2K2H3ctKIhYTT6SzHmYIHqocyq7p3EbtQSumzBaeuMy2zfoIbWBq3HUq1ZUt2JdpcsQfmYH3Ff2l+Y01EM3Bn1V0PSdPSUkSnqvm7MFNcIs7jmgEaChYYosbdIGog009Q8lKsUV8w2FeKwCipxArLkBFLMgyuqwiRyquYIL5Vez7qHy1cxohXkz9SnD61OeVPkUaR0IBW7zqzyhCjC6a1YyMOFg0VtbHs4ZUUs9Rla44gxeo/ycscn5js4jdhhW7iXWqnKaqqlNsMLxIcurAXHvKgWVQqFKbrzGpr9VVQzirTsFT8Qc5Yql7KMiVV9LMqGT0ZByhS/EquEcLqiegb7IRYhtmE1C4poasT1CVAsinsPZxHsizeVzYynyvmIKADlIAvtguuIiYn8EDyuo34W6XuR4qNGkHBzfgxpy6jaEmEEgMtuKBdEcaUDQPJ+YbUL5alSi8R4pctWKQJTsOMB9xW57qsNtbruDQzlCq5dM5ZeEiC9kbsYuWmFDmXDKcbyRhmZ05lBXLLRoNzK9sUij4lG2nHMCOGYz0z3niGo+Guw0jPwVL/AIULlsAYC6wfKy4HewcADO9yw0ADQB1KrglBV0iA5ah5IaWoo5Y8MqRh/P3S9j3ys5oXvtV/FmI+LKuWoJdFcS70GK6lq2HqKRc6iJaO2F6t/cSNLq8fctaY7oO9zFdM9Fm/ACstRLRp5H7W/MtmNCz4L8vxG70tH0PEdt2yxRVazLEWd1pXhZCv3mXUEmGBC3J9uWXQgaFbWduAPmKF1bCApmAvAhoblowy+IQFaXhgWLwUdpe6dGMhYVaLduJdPKyq5cc3C/Dcyx2f05qAPc7rUJR9w0RCCJCxFTeLtgyenIItK7Cy4FCuHNMvnMbYtSXhRbPgCAEzZSxKWoBCLYYZL7iClxKTEscNlbKt/bKioomZlAleSrypmHMp8JTA8y4S1fxCXAzLGeY8URzVcq4RKM2Zft/DLn6iRVH2IAq3HSD7QcuoBW84IhRdmPEO0n0ksYsoVW5f7ineHgxcZEAazEKeFt4wrbFrTsP+xMdIAJ4qJMilw852PJLCsycDpnmZqrPGYlLXoISmWjugEzqtPcPYBgbAD9RcksbzLnTLTEyiqWLeeVgNOGzG4kDn6S1UNjaR1QFrYRD1xaIroLT9SxbgxO85fA3FNq6dt5BUPZGr8gADqlIvLAIWdP8A5KGYoOB3nb6gNrxph7NPtIlqcw6o7CvwgqHBSi26u09RV4sEG72vZgiDg4g+oDE4P8I/UdlZXha7dShw8hHoYwehvsl+i5uiewmvmFUSso+aIPwQtY1ahzT0dRcAZAxOiaefxHkGkvD2obL4ipoYAawRIZWC0ZghWUdZ+ec3G4iqgd1X7jcgI7AF/cF8USksDw3xHbpPer0MBLalm/WCA6hbYA7cTkMzXndGYGH2Cq+VX9orsSjK+hl+xOkWfV1El53RW+FiYFYGTtHbr8Iv5lbKA7qvAdZ6l7cyJkHkz5ItAw1WK+oOM3aPQvE2qx2rG5P/AARFrIs/MNJsZ4PMJTLxfj5iWTKuzlxrUMSsSChQDS+4FBZHvrbkfBAe8aJ0W1PcL/FjApzhTDUSlmtBi6LY2mV2TNZClYBkxYmmAEF0TTumJZueW/iVBtsi6y0wvggX7oH0A5Y5W8ZEeHUZ8MdznFoK+4/54AlqtlOdxhPWuz8QmQOBphHMf4EL3z8o7lZ4hyV9yLKD3Ig3y1b9zKVI3dER9rUPvDCJ3hBRxYU/ZGQOSVeeKaMBKb7u9cVHty1xh2VsPmUR1S36MRN2+Be0lwDkKOOyo+e4WS+JVGDwi4l0vajtP0scMxX/AHJ+3R0T/9k=
```

This one is really long and generated by the website http://www.base64-image.de/step-1.php

However, my application code generates a Base64 that looks like this

```
_9j_4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD_2wBDAAYEBQ
```

It is shorter and I don't know why. Could someone please explain to me how to get the long version? Thankyou so much. Below is the code I am using to get the short version. I have obviously spent a long time Googling to figure this out and no one seems interested in this long thing.

```
String file1 = "C:\\Users\\J\\Desktop\\test5.jpg";

System.out.println("HERE");

FileInputStream imageInFile = new FileInputStream(file1);
byte imageData[] = new byte[(int) file1.length()];
imageInFile.read(imageData);

byte[] encodedBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(imageData);

System.out.println("encodedBytes " + new String(encodedBytes));

String convertedImageData = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(imageData);

System.out.println(convertedImageData);
```

Below is the output of both of those:

```
HERE
encodedBytes /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/2wBDAAYEBQ==
_9j_4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD_2wBDAAYEBQ
```

Thanks for reading. I have tried MANY different things and come here now to ask.

Comment: How large is the image data? Do a `sysout` of the length of the byte[]

Comment: thankyou for the answer, the length is 40

Comment: Methods Base64.encodeBase64 and Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString do not exist anymore with a more recent Java version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
imageInFile.read(imageData);
```

does not read the whole file into the array.

It reads some bytes length matching its internal buffer and returns as the result the number actually read.
You need to repeat the process in a loop till read no longer returns the data.
Check the javadoc.

Comment: When i printlined imageData it gave me `[B@8efb846` which I thought was weird but i'm in no position to question it. I will look into that, thankyou so much

Comment: I was failing to figure out how to do what you said. I accidently went back to the first example I was following hours ago and saw that he was referring to a File filepath instead of a String filepath. When i changed this and reverted my code, I have suddenly been given the LONG BASE64. the code I copied (badly) is located at http://myjeeva.com/how-to-convert-image-to-string-and-string-to-image-in-java.html Thankyou everyone. Ill see if it works now

Comment: was still getting 404 even with "long" base64, fixed by changing syntax `String a1 = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(imageData);` to `String a1 = Base64.encodeBase64String(imageData);` (thanks guy from 8 months ago)

Answer (score 0):

Try these methods:

```
public static String imgToBase64String(final RenderedImage img, final String formatName) {
    final ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        ImageIO.write(img, formatName, Base64.getEncoder().wrap(os));
        return os.toString(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1.name());
    } catch (final IOException ioe) {
        throw new UncheckedIOException(ioe);
    }
}

public static BufferedImage base64StringToImg(final String base64String) {
    try {
        return ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64String)));
    } catch (final IOException ioe) {
        throw new UncheckedIOException(ioe);
    }
}
```

Taken from: [Java BufferedImage to PNG format Base64 String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7178937/java-bufferedimage-to-png-format-base64-string)

Comment: thankyou for your answer but it looks like i had an error in reading the file in the first place (see one of my other comments)

Comment: Yeah you commented the size after I posted the answer

Answer (score 0):

The years have passed...

Nowadays, I think the solution can be fount here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/url-encoding-decoding-using-base64-in-java/

So this worked for me:

```
Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);
```

To get the `byte[] bytes` (completely) filled as another topic...

I tested adding an html inline image when sending an email...

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,_9j_4AAQSkZ...
```